# Invalid cursor position when inserting a blob

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, db2, odbc, db2-luw

I have an old MFC project that I'm trying to update. It's updated from VS2008 to VS2017. Database is also replaced from some old DB2, to DB2 Server Edition 11.5 (Community license). In new environment I can't insert a row containing a blob. I get error **CLI0148E  Invalid cursor position. SQLSTATE=S1109**. I installed ODBC driver from path C:<DB2 Install Path>\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2CLI.DLL.

**Important note**: If I insert a row without a blob then the operation is successful. So, it's not an error with the setup, or configuration, or whatnot.

The code is pretty standard. I tested this code in MFC demo app (some strings are modified to protect the innocent):

```
class SetExample : public CRecordset
{
public:
    SetExample(CDatabase* pDatabase);
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(SetExample)

protected:
    CByteArray m_ByteArray;
    COleDateTime m_DateTime;
    int m_Int;

public:
    virtual void DoFieldExchange(CFieldExchange* pFX);
    virtual CString GetDefaultSQL();

    bool AddRecord(const CByteArray & byteArray);
};

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(SetExample, CRecordset)

SetExample::SetExample(CDatabase* pDatabase) : CRecordset(pDatabase)
{
    m_nFields = 3; // Set to 2 to make insert work
    m_nDefaultType = snapshot;
}

void SetExample::DoFieldExchange(CFieldExchange* pFX)
{
    pFX->SetFieldType(CFieldExchange::outputColumn);
    RFX_Binary(pFX, _T("[SOME_BLOB]"), m_ByteArray, INT_MAX); // Comment this to make insert work. SOME_BLOB is nullable in database
    RFX_Date(pFX, _T("[SOME_DATETIME]"), m_DateTime);
    RFX_Int(pFX, _T("[SOME_INT]"), m_Int);
}

CString SetExample::GetDefaultSQL()
{
    return _T("ADMIN.EXAMPLE");
}

bool SetExample::AddRecord(IN const CByteArray &byteArray)
{
    if (!Open())
        return false;

    AddNew();

    m_ByteArray.Copy(byteArray);
    m_DateTime = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
    m_Int = 42;

    if (!Update())
        return false;

    Close();

    return true;
}


void CMFCApplicationDlg::OnBnClickedTest()
{
    CDatabase db;

    if (!db.Open(_T("<EXAMPLE_DNS>"), FALSE, FALSE, _T("DSN=<EXAMPLE_DNS>; UID=<username>; PWD=<password>; MODE=SHARE; DBALIAS=<EXAMPLE_ALIAS>;")))
        return;

    SetExample setExample(&db);

    CByteArray byteArray;
    byteArray.Add(1);
    byteArray.Add(2);

    if (!setExample.AddRecord(byteArray))
        return;
}
```

So, why BLOB can't be inserted, and (more importantly) how to fix it?

Both client and server side are on my laptop, Windows 10. db2level command reports this:

```
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11054" with level identifier
"0605010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.4000.1449", "s2006161200",
"DYN2006161200WIN64", and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".
```

**Update**: I updated DB2 to latest available, as per mao's comment, but the issue is still present.

Comment: @mao, added more info.

Comment: You are using the build dated 15.Dec.2016 . Suggest you apply latest fixpack and retry, download from https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-db2-fix-packs-version-db2-linux-unix-and-windows  . If not possible, or if it does not help, take a CLI trace to see what's happening under the covers (instructions for CLI trace are in Db2 Knowledge Center online).  Sometimes there are more details in the db2diag.log

Comment: What does a CLI trace tell you? (See Db2 Knowledge Centre for instructions for capturing the trace and then formatting the binary trace so that it is readable text ).  Also, when the insert blob fails, are there any special messages in the db2diag.log file ?

Comment: @mao, I turned db2trc on, ran the example above, and it produced 11 MB dump file (24 MB log file). I can't find anything in there, it's too big. I have a feeling that the problem is in ODBC driver, and that it's a well known problem. It's not possible that only me and my colleague have come across it. It affects C++ code, but not C# code (similar C# code using ODBC does work with BLOB).

Comment: If you make a small console app that only does an insert with blob, and trace only that, then it should be manageable to read if you use the `db2trc fmt -cli  dumpfilename  trace.txt`, and you are looking for SQL_ERROR or SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO.  As far as I know both the C++ code and C# code both use the same IBM Db2 driver.

Comment: Been toying with -cli option, and now got "SQL0270N  Function not supported (Reason code = "53")". 53 means "A column with a LONG VARCHAR, LONG VARGRAPHIC, LOB, or XML type, a distinct type on any of these types, or a structured type cannot be specified in the select-list of a scrollable cursor." Great, but now what..

Comment: Please confirm this (SQL0270N, reason 53) is what you see in the cli trace, and that the app only sees the CLI0148E.   Also, please edit your question to show the *exact* column datatype (look in syscat.columns for your table+column), and also the database encoding (`db2 get db cfg for $dbname`)

Comment: I confirm what I'm seeing. This error is actually the only line in the log file, after the <db2trc_header>. Word "encoding" is not found in the text produced by the command above. Database code set is UTF-8. Type of EXAMPLE.SOME_BLOB is BLOB (as seen in SYSCAT.COLUMNS).

Comment: Need to examine the settings in Visual Studio / mfc  to vary the cursor scrollability (perhaps they are default?). In Db2 terms, perhaps a forward-only cursor would functionally suffice, although I don't know how to tell that to the classes you are using in the app. Something to research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220936/discussion-between-mao-and-dialecticus).

Comment: Have you been able to detect which ODBC call returns the "Invalid cursor position" error from the trace file? Is it an SQLSetPos call? If you got a working version by replacing the CByteArray, you can compare the two traces, to see how they differ and why the latest version of the code works. You can also use the Windows ODBC tracing. It can be enabled in ODBC Administartor .